# jQuery toggle (Click to show one div while hiding others)

Tags: jquery, toggle

The basic idea is that I have a bunch of div's in which each can be toggled (show/hide).

When one div is toggled I'd like for other div's that are currently being shown to hide, thus only allowing one single div to be shown at a time.

In addition I'd like to be able to click outside the element to hide the open div as well.

Just to make things clearer I provided an example which currently does everything I want except closing a div when opening another (Only one div open at a time functionality):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('div.dropdown').each(function() {
    var $dropdown = $(this);

    $("a.dropdown-link", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown).toggle();
      return false;
    });

});
    
  $('html').click(function(){
    $("div.dropdown-container").hide();
  });
     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-2" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-3" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does accordion do what you want? http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Comment: @KieranAndrews: Sounds like it, except that it doesn't auto-close when you click somewhere else.

Comment: There is a setting for that, let me find it.

Comment: Sorry, accordion is a bit much for what I'm looking for. I'd rather keep is lightweight without the need of plugins.

Comment: My answer will do all that you've asked, without closing the menu when you click on a menu item (which other answers have missed...).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You basically just need to hide all divs except the one being toggled:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('div.dropdown').each(function() {
    var $dropdown = $(this);

    $("a.dropdown-link", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $div = $("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown);
      $div.toggle();
      $("div.dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
      return false;
    });

});
    
  $('html').click(function(){
    $("div.dropdown-container").hide();
  });
     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-2" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-3" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte I believe that behavior was intended originally.  I thought he said it specifically, but his question actually doesn't specify.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte  Explosion Pills is correct. Sorry for the confusion I should have been more clear when writing the question instead of just adding the example.

Answer (score 4):

You can use by smart and easy way to implement by using below code :

```
<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-2" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-3" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".dropdown-link").click(function(){
 $(".dropdown-container").slideUp('slow')
 $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-container').slideDown('slow');
 
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-2" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-3" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example Link : http://jsfiddle.net/NFTFw/1901/

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("a.dropdown-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $div = $(this).next('.dropdown-container');
    $(".dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
    if ($div.is(":visible")) {
        $div.hide()
    }  else {
       $div.show();
    }
});

   $(document).click(function(e){
       var p = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length
       if (!p) {
          $(".dropdown-container").hide();
       }
   });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6t6BP/4)

Answer (score 2):

I made it as short as possible! Happy coding!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "a", function(event){
    $(this).siblings().show()
    $(this).parent().siblings().each(function(index,element){
       $(element).find(".dropdown-container:visible").hide();
    });
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NFTFw/60/

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick, without the use of additional libraries. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/NFTFw/42/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var dd = $(".dropdown-container");

  $("a.dropdown-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    dd.hide();
    $(this).next().show();
  });

  $(document).click(function() {
    dd.hide();
  });

  dd.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Comment: You can't click an open div's link to close it again with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$("a.dropdown-link", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".dropdown-container").hide();
  $("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown).toggle();
  return false;
});
```

Note the added line:

```
$(".dropdown-container").hide();
```

We just hide all the things before toggling the div we want.

Comment: Then you can't click the link of an open div to close it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $('div.dropdown').each(function() {
        var $dropdown = $(this);

        $("a.dropdown-link", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("div.dropdown-container").hide();
            if($("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown).hide()){
                $("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown).show();
            }else{
                $("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown).hide();
            }
          return false;
        });

    });

      $('html').click(function(){
        $("div.dropdown-container").hide();
      });

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NFTFw/40/

Comment: You can't click an open div link to close it again; the `.hide()` check first and then the makeshift toggle does not solve that problem.