# How to close all other accordions in multiple sections when I open one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

EDIT: **I've found the solution without use of jQuery UI accordion:
 [Jquery toggle (Click to show one div while hiding others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769270/jquery-toggle-click-to-show-one-div-while-hiding-others)**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sy34v/  (don't mind blank space on left, it's probably because disabled list numbering)

If I open one accordion lets say on "List Window 1" it stays open even if I click on another accordion in "List Window 2".

So if I have 4 accordion sections there can be 4 accordions opened. How to make it so that only one accordion on whole page can be opened and if I open another then last will close? It works like that only inside accordion section.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".listWindow").accordion({
        header: ".accordionHeader",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186993/close-accordions-if-other-accordian-is-open-in-jquery

Comment: @andrew it doesn't work on jQuery 1.11.0 and jQuery UI 1.10.4 see: http://jsfiddle.net/aH2m5/

Comment: the example you provided works fine, the css need sorting out though

Comment: for me it works exactly like my code in question - i can open multiple accordions and not only 1

Comment: I've found the solution without use of jQuery UI accordion:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769270/jquery-toggle-click-to-show-one-div-while-hiding-others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this solutin

http://jsfiddle.net/rm7fD/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var titleClicked = "";

$(".listWindow").accordion({
    header: ".accordionHeader",
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        var title = $(this).find(".title").html(); 
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(titleClicked == title){
                $(".listWindow").each(function(){
                    if ($(this).find(".title").html() != title){                       
                        $(this).accordion("option", "active", false);
                    }
                });
           }
        }, 100);
    }
});  

$(".siteTitle").click(function () {
    event.stopPropagation();        
});

$(".accordionWrapper").click(function(){        
    titleClicked = $(this).closest(".listWindow").find(".title").text();
});

});
```

Comment: It works but kinda wonky because when I click fast then it bugs out, but thanks for helping

Comment: try again, i have modified without timer

Comment: edited fiddle sometimes closes immediately opened accordion also

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that approach ?

```
$(function() {
    var $accordions = $(".listWindow").accordion({
        header: ".accordionHeader",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    }).on('click', function() {
        $accordions.not(this).accordion('activate', false);
    });
});
```

Based on: [Close accordions if other accordian is open in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186993/close-accordions-if-other-accordian-is-open-in-jquery)

Comment: Yup, but it doesn't work on jQuery 1.11.0 and jQuery UI 1.10.4