# Jquery multitude plus/minus buttons using visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to modify the solution found in the answer of this question:

[Jquery toggle (Click to show one div while hiding others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769270/jquery-toggle-click-to-show-one-div-while-hiding-others)

but insted of show/hide I need to change visible/hidden status, this because my divs elements has to take up space on the page remaining in a fixed position and not drop-down. 
this is my jquery code:

```
$(".sticker").click(function(){
    var gid = $(this).attr('id');
    var id = gid.split("-")[1];

    if ($(this).children("img").attr("src")=="img/plus.png") {
        $(this).children("img").attr("src","img/minus.png");
        $('#'+id).addClass('visible');
    } 
    else {
        $(this).children("img").attr("src","img/plus.png");
        $('#'+id).removeClass('visible');
    }

});
```

the html code:

```
<div id="container">
 <div class="more" id="one">
  <div class="info">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="sticker" id="sticker-one"><img src="img/plus.png" width="28" height="28" /></div>

 <div class="more" id="two">
  <div class="info">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="sticker" id="sticker-two"><img src="img/plus.png" width="28" height="28" /></div>

 <div class="more" id="three">
  <div class="info">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="sticker" id="sticker-three"><img src="img/plus.png" width="28" height="28" /></div>
</div>
```

the "visible" css class is =

```
.visible {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/dux6e1dt/)

I would like to hide the visibility also to the ".more" opened div when click over a new "sticker" in order to have only one div opened per time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be working fine. You might only need to set `!important` because it seems it will not become visible on class change

```
.visible {
    visibility:visible !important;
}
```

***Here is also a more compact modified code.***

```js
$(".sticker").click(function() {

  var $t = $(this);
  var $img = $t.children("img");

  if ($img[0].src.indexOf('plus') > -1) {
    $img[0].src = 'img/minus.png';
    $t.prev('.more').addClass('visible');
  } else {
    $img[0].src = 'img/plus.png';
    $t.prev('.more').removeClass('visible');
  }

});
```

```css
.visible {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
.more {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="more" id="one">
    <div class="info">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sticker" id="sticker-one">
    <img src="img/plus.png" width="28" height="28" />
  </div>

  <div class="more" id="two">
    <div class="info">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sticker" id="sticker-two">
    <img src="img/plus.png" width="28" height="28" />
  </div>

  <div class="more" id="three">
    <div class="info">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sticker" id="sticker-three">
    <img src="img/plus.png" width="28" height="28" />
  </div>
</div>
```

***And here is your code in action***

```js
$(".sticker").click(function(){
    var gid = $(this).attr('id');
    var id = gid.split("-")[1];

    if ($(this).children("img").attr("src")=="img/plus.png") {
        $(this).children("img").attr("src","img/minus.png");
        $('#'+id).addClass('visible');
    } 
    else {
        $(this).children("img").attr("src","img/plus.png");
        $('#'+id).removeClass('visible');
    }

});
```

```css
.visible {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
.more {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="more" id="one">
    <div class="info">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sticker" id="sticker-one">
    <img src="img/plus.png" width="28" height="28" />
  </div>

  <div class="more" id="two">
    <div class="info">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sticker" id="sticker-two">
    <img src="img/plus.png" width="28" height="28" />
  </div>

  <div class="more" id="three">
    <div class="info">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sticker" id="sticker-three">
    <img src="img/plus.png" width="28" height="28" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved both using visibility and display.

1. display = none/block:

css

```
.visible {
 display: none;
 }
```

js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sticker").each(function() {
        var $t = $(this);
        var $img = $t.children("img");
        var $m = $t.prev();

        $($t).on('click', function(){
            if ($img[0].src.indexOf('plus') > -1) {
                $img[0].src = 'img/minus.png';
                $t.prev('.more').toggle();
              } else {
                $img[0].src = 'img/plus.png';
                $t.prev('.more').toggle();
              } 
            $('.more').not($m[0]).hide();   
            var r = $('.sticker').children("img").not($img);
            r[0].src = 'img/plus.png';
            r[1].src = 'img/plus.png';
        });
    });
    });
```

2. visibility = hidden/visible:

Putting in each click event the ".more" div in the array.

For example the array after 5 clicks will be:

arr = ["zero", div#one.more, div#two.more.visible, div#three.more, div#two.more.visible, div#one.more]

Then creating 2 variables $prev and $current.

$prev gets the id of the ".more" div that has been opened previously,   "$current" gets the id of the current opened div.
Then removing the 'visible' class at the previous div and adding 'visible' class at the current div.

css

```
.more {
  position: absolute;
  visibility:hidden;
 }

.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var $arr = Array();

    $arr[i] = "zero";

    $(".sticker").each(function() {
        var $t = $(this);
        var $img = $t.children("img");
        var $m = $t.prev();

        function change() {
            $img[0].src = 'img/minus.png';
            $t.prev('.more').addClass('visible');
        }


        $($t).on('click', function() {
            var $d = $m[0];
            i++;

            $arr[i] = $d;

            $prev = $($arr[i - 1]).attr('id');

            $current = $($arr[i]).attr('id');

            if ($img[0].src.indexOf('minus') > -1) {

                $img[0].src = 'img/plus.png';
                $t.prev('.more').removeClass('visible');
            } else if (i > 1 && $img[0].src.indexOf('plus') > -1 && $prev != $current) {

                $("#" + $prev).removeClass('visible');

                var myimg = $("#" + $prev).next('.sticker').children("img");

                myimg[0].src = 'img/plus.png';

                change();

            } else if ($img[0].src.indexOf('plus') > -1 && $prev == $current || $arr[1]) {

                change();
            }
        });
    });
});
```